# Does an “unreasonable command” include commanding a good outsider to do an evil act?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, alignment

I was reading planar binding description, hoping to have an evil wizard NPC use the spell to bind angels and archons to his will. The condition "Impossible demands or unreasonable commands are never agreed to", gives me pause, since I'm not sure if that gets in the way of my plans.

Is the evil spellcaster asking an angel to do something evil considered an "unreasonable command" that would not be agreed to? Or does an unreasonable command only mean something like "destroy the entire city of waterdeep in 3 seconds"?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/35684/8610), albeit for *Pathfinder.*

Comment: This still might yet run afoul of our “alignment debates are off topic” rule, but we'll see how the votes, comments, and answers go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wording of the spell tells me that they are talking about “unreasonable” demands in some *objective* sense—not “unreasonable to the particular thing you have bound,” but “unreasonable to *everyone*,” (or at least most everyone). It’s subjective about what counts or doesn’t, but the bound creature’s moral and ethical objections should not be considered in assessing whether or not the command is reasonable.

As evidence, I would contrast the wording in *planar binding* to the wording in *dominate person*, which specifies that “any subject forced to take actions against its nature receives a new saving throw with a +2 bonus”—since *planar binding* fails to make any mention of actions “against its nature,” I would interpret that as not applying to *planar binding*.

Note that *planar binding* gains the good descriptor when used to bind a good creature. It is commonly assumed that casting a spell with a particular descriptor is an act matching that alignment, that shifts you closer to that alignment. The rules do not actually say this (excepting in *Book of Exalted Deeds*, and then only with respect to evil spells, but *Book of Exalted Deeds* is awful), but you should discuss with your DM what his or her views on the subject are. Presumably whatever evil you’re forcing the good creature to do outweighs any good from the spell, and even if not it should take many,  many castings to actually shift your alignment, but the discussion is worth having.

Comment: *Not starting an alignment debate!* Outside of the *Book of Exalted Deeds* or *Vile Darkness*, where is it said that—like [channeling positive energy](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#neutral-clerics-and-undead)—casting a good spell is a good act?

Comment: @HeyICanChan OK, “explicitly” I believe the example is that casting an [Evil] spell is an Evil act (I believe the *DMG* says this?), and I am extrapolating from that for other alignments—which, to be fair, may not actually be true, the alignments are not actually equal.

Comment: I can find but one evil act in the *DMG* (the awesomely specific *trying to dupe someone into buying a cursed item* on 277) and *no* good acts. Really, I recommend deleting that clause unless you *want* to cite *Exalted Deeds* (e.g. "The use of evil spells, obviously, is not good even when the target is evil" (10)).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, I’ve offered a half-measure between. Good, or still better to just remove, you think?

Comment: Were it my answer, I'd remove it. I'd really like a much deeper line in the sand to separate good *behavior* (which the site *can't* discuss) from good *acts* (which the site is reluctant to discuss yet shouldn't be).  However, I think the answer couches the distinction sufficiently to at least send folks elsewhere if they're hunting for proof as to whether casting a good spell is a good act.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I strongly disagree with your assertion that the site shouldn’t be hesitant to discuss aligned acts. But then my vocal and vehement disregard for alignment as a concept altogether is well-known.

Comment: Not to mention that most people can't actually define what good and evil are, in and of themselves, but can only give examples of things or acts that could be considered one or the other, from a certain point of view. ^^